# Excel previously changed text to dates. How do I get it back to what I originally typed?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, format, date, microsoft-excel-365

I have a large Excel (xlsx) spreadsheet full of various types of data. I had initially downloaded this data from Google Sheets. At some point (I'm not sure when), one of my columns of data that had number ranges as text (format `1-2`, `2-3`, etc.) got converted automatically to dates. For example, the value `2-3` got converted to `3-Feb` in the cell (and `2/3/2022` in the function box).

I understand there are many techniques for *preventing* this (e.g., including adding a  ` in front of the text), but my question is not about prevention but rather *reversal.*

**How do I recover auto-date-formatted cells to show me the *original* text the cell contained before auto reformatting?**

If my cell contained `2-3`, I just want to make it say `2-3` again. How do I do this?

- Is this information even saved?

Of course -- as many of us have frustratingly done over the last 20 years --I try changing the cells' formats to `Text` or `General`, but I just end up with Excel's 5-digit serial date code. I instead want my original text.

Comment: What about `=TEXT(<date cell>;"D-M")`?

Comment: @JohnSUN yes, such an approach would get me back to the formatting I need (well, at least with the slight modification of your second argument to `"M-D"`), but I was wondering if there was some way to do this without having to create new cells/columns of data. I just want to quickly convert my existing column back to its original text. (One other issue, too, is that not every cell in the column contains this date format -- some cells, for example, still contain text like `10 or more`).

Comment: Well, actually, @JohnSUN, upon further testing, your function (again modified to be `=TEXT(<date cell>;"M-D")`) maintains text like `10 or more` while converting all the dates. So, thank, you, this is a blanket solution for recovering these data. I welcome you to add it as an answer. However, to others, I'm still curious if there is a way to do this without having to create a new column of data (i.e., I'd like to be able to simply reformat the existing column of data). thanks!

Comment: That would be VBA code, Loop through the cells and apply WorksheetFunction.text(...)   *as above* on each one (?) - haven't tried it though. LINK -> https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=WorksheetFunction+VBA